# Having trouble seeing YouTube video in Drupal 7 using Media and Media YouTube

Tags: media

I'm having trouble seeing YouTube video in Drupal 7 using Media and Media YouTube.

I've followed this tutorial but I never seem to get a video to show up on my page.
http://www.cleverlogic.net/tutorials/drupal-7-video-setup-using-media-and-media-youtube-module

Another thing I've noticed is that when I add a video to some content type, I never see the video's thumbnail.

No errors seem to get displayed.

I'm using Drupal 7, 
Media 7.x-1.0-rc2
Media YouTube 7.x-1.0-alpha5

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I had the same issue months ago, try the dev version or checkout the [issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/media_youtube?categories=bug) for errors, for example [this one](http://drupal.org/node/1134966) says you need the dev version of the Styles module.

Comment: For anyone else having problem with this video (I'm the author), I've made an updated one at http://gleamly.com/article/setup-video-your-drupal-website-using-media-and-mediayoutube that explains the new Media and Media:Youtube modules.

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, the [video_embed_field](http://drupal.org/project/video_embed_field) module now works well for youtube and vimeo videos.

Comment: I can see this coming in handy. +1ed Thanks for the link / tip, Merry Xmas

Answer (score 3):

Go to admin/structure/file-types/manage/video/file-display and make sure the youtube displays are enabled for the correct viewmode.  You may need to create a new viewmode with Display Suite module or entity view mode module.

Then go to your content type at /admin/structure/types/manage/article/display and set the field to "rendered entity" and choose the correct viewmode.

Hope that helps